# Changing UIActivityViewController share modal navigation bar to opaque on iOS15

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios15

I'm getting a transparent navigation bar in share modal controllers on iOS 15. But navbar appearance were properly set already and is not changed at any part of the app. This issue only happens from uiactivity share modals and not all .

**Appearance setup**

```
 // AppDelegate.swift

if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .white
        appearance.shadowImage = nil
        appearance.shadowColor = .clear
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.BananaGrotesk(weight: .semibold, size: 16.0),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.Function.black
        ]
        navBarAppearance.barTintColor = .white
        navBarAppearance.standardAppearance = appearance
        navBarAppearance.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        navBarAppearance.compactAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        navBarAppearance.isTranslucent = false
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
        
        //  Remove bottom line aka shadow
        navBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navBarAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navBarAppearance.tintColor = .clear
        navBarAppearance.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
        //  Update bar title font
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.BananaGrotesk(weight: .semibold, size: 16.0),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.Function.black
        ]
    }
 }
```

---

**What I've tried and it does nothing.**

```
func presentShareActivity(items: [Any]) {
    //let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["test share copy"], applicationActivities: nil)
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .white
        appearance.shadowImage = nil
        appearance.shadowColor = .clear
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.BananaGrotesk(weight: .semibold, size: 16.0),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.Function.black
        ]
        activityVC.navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        activityVC.navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
        activityVC.navigationItem.compactAppearance = appearance
        activityVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        activityVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        activityVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        activityVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
    }
    present(activityVC, animated: true)
}
```

**Screenshots**

Navigation bar is transparent but turns opaque on scroll. I want this to be opaque

[image]

Interestingly the photo below uses the same code but has an opaque navbar

[image]

Comment: Hi, perhaps a conflict with an appearance set in your code. Did you try to comment temporary all the place where you define navigation to transparent ? that should explain why it doesn't append every time.

Comment: @Hikosei thanks for the suggestion. Whats on the post is already all the appearance related code I have in my application. Its really just on Appdelegate and then on the activity presentation method which whether its there or not, nothing changes.

Comment: Can you share a sample project ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
activityVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
```

It worked for me.